# Distinct Values Ignoring Column Order

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table similar to:-

```
+----+---+---+
| Id | A | B |
+----+---+---+    
| 1  | 1 | 2 |
+----+---+---+
| 2  | 2 | 1 |
+----+---+---+
| 3  | 3 | 4 |
+----+---+---+
| 4  | 0 | 5 |
+----+---+---+
| 5  | 5 | 0 |
+----+---+---+
```

I want to remove all duplicate pairs of values, regardless of which column contains which value, e.g. after whatever the query might be I want to see:-

```
+----+---+---+
| Id | A | B |
+----+---+---+    
| 1  | 1 | 2 |
+----+---+---+
| 3  | 3 | 4 |
+----+---+---+
| 4  | 0 | 5 |
+----+---+---+
```

I'd like to find a solution in Microsoft SQL Server (has to work in <= 2005, though I'd be interested in any solutions which rely upon >= 2008 features regardless).

In addition, note that A and B are going to be in the range 1-100 (but that's not guaranteed forever. They are surrogate seeded integer foreign keys, however the foreign table might grow to a couple hundred rows max).

I'm wondering whether I'm missing some obvious solution here. The ones which have occurred all seem rather overwrought, though I do think they'd probably work, e.g.:-

- Have a subquery return a bitfield with each bit corresponding to one of the ids and use this value to remove duplicates.
- Somehow, pivot, remove duplicates, then unpivot. Likely to be tricky.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This sounds like a modeling issue too.  If you don't care which value is in which column then the columns both represent the same data and should probably be normalized.

Comment: @JNK - agreed, absolutely, however as is often the case in these scenarios the model cannot be modified at this point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
select min(Id) Id, A, B
from (select Id, A, B from DuplicatesTable where A <= B
      union all
      select Id, B A, A B from DuplicatesTable where A > B) v
group by A, B
order by 1
```

Comment: +1 Because I like the use of the where clauses in your sub queries to avoid the dupes.  Note that the sub query needs an alias though.

Comment: I couldn't remember whether SQLServer required subquery aliases or not (not all SQLs do), but I have added one now.

Answer (score 6):

Test data and sample below.

Basically, we do a self join with an `OR` criteria so either a=a and b=b OR a=b and b=a.

The `WHERE` in the subquery gives you the max for each pair to eliminate.

I think this should work for triplicates as well (note I added a 6th row).

```
DECLARE @t table(id int, a int, b int)

INSERT INTO @t
VALUES
(1,1,2),
(2,2,1),
(3,3,4),
(4,0,5),
(5,5,0),
(6,5,0)

SELECT *
FROM @t
WHERE id NOT IN (
                SELECT a.id
                FROM @t a
                INNER JOIN @t b
                    ON (a.a=b.a
                    AND a.b=b.b)
                    OR
                    (a.b=b.a
                    AND a.a = b.b)
                WHERE a.id > b.id)
```

Answer (score 4):

Not 100% tested and I'm sure it can be tidied up but it produces your required result:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (id INT IDENTITY(1,1), A INT, B INT)

INSERT INTO @T
VALUES (1,2), (2,1), (3,4), (0,5), (5,0);

SELECT * 
FROM @T
WHERE id IN (SELECT DISTINCT MIN(id)
             FROM (SELECT id, a, b 
                   FROM @T
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT id, b, a
                   FROM @T) z
             GROUP BY a, b)
```

Comment: Why are you obfuscating by using a `CTE` that just returns the table?

Comment: +1 Because taking the UNION of (A, B) and (B, A) is novel solution. However it doesn't scale well. For example if you add a third column C then you would need the UNION of (A,B,C), (A, C, B) , (B, A, C), (B, C, A), (C, A, B) and (C, B, A). JNK's solution requires a modification to the JOIN clause.